# Wi-Fi turning on and off since Mavericks upgrade

Tags: wifi, macos

MacBook Pro
Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013

Since upgrading to Mavericks, the Wi-Fi turns off for roughly 8 seconds and turn back on for roughly 8 seconds. I have tried this on several different networks in different physical locations. It seems to be the exact same symptoms as described in [this Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23468484#23468484) - even turning Wi-Fi off manually doesn't help (it just turns right back on again).

I tried this and rebooting, but it didn't work

> Try backing up and then deleting this file:
> `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
>
> from this folder:
> `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`

In fact, none of the suggestions in the thread seemed to work.

I would rather not go through the trouble of downgrading since Ethernet works.

Comment: Downgrading to 10.8.4 immediately fixed the issue. Also, I realize that this would be considered hearsay; however, a gentleman from the help desk where I work mentioned that Apple has acknowledged this issue and there is yet to be a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a custom script running under a subdirectory of `/Library/Scripts/` on this laptop. It looked something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dscacheutil -flushcache
if ifconfig en0 | grep inet;
then 
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en2 off
else
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en2 on
fi
```

Commenting its insides out fixed the problem The Wi-Fi no long periodically disconnects. I'm guessing that between 10.8 and 10.9, one of the commands in that script changed.